# display Count of one column from another table even when the count is zero

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, nvl

I have two tables **A and B**. In Table A (Oracle sql), an unique column(not primary key) **code** may have some records in table B.

**Example:**

Code "A" has 3 entries, Code "B" has 2 entries and code "C" has 0 entries in table B.  I want the query to display the code and its count of records in Table B.

```
A 3
B 2
C 0,
```

But i am not getting the code with zero records in table B, **i.e C 0.**

Please anyone can help me with the query.

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY, and count.

Comment: I tried with that.. But not getting it correctly.. Cn u pls tell me the exact query for the above scenario

Comment: Show us sample table data, your query (the one that doesn't work properly), and expected result!

Comment: SAmple Table A

Code  name

A        pal
B        john
C        APril

Table B

Code   Value

A          10
A           20
B           30


SAMple Out put:

Code    NoofEntries

A           2
B           1
C           0

Comment: My query: select a.code,a.name,count(b.code) from A a, B b where a.code=b.code group by a.code, a.name;

Comment: With the above query i am not getting "C 0" in my Output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` with `LEFT JOIN` solution:

```
select a.code,
       a.name,
       count(b.code)
from A a
  LEFT JOIN B b ON a.code = b.code
group by a.code, a.name
```

Correlated sub-query solution:

```
select a.code,
       a.name,
       (select count(*) from B b where a.code = b.code)
from A a
```

Perhaps you need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` here.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something incorrectly. This works for me:

```
select A.code, Count(B.code) from A
left join B on A.code = b.code
group by A.code
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f13e1/2

Comment: This is perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy, you just need to Take column base on you want count as I did **"A.code"** and don't forget to Group by that column, and use **COUNT()**.
    Check the below solution

```
   select A.code, Count(B.code) AS Count 
    from A
    left join B on A.code = b.code
    group by A.code
```